# With Statement not working when launching external cmd process

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Can someone explain why when i start a new process like this:

```
 Dim pi2 As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", String.Format("/c ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000"))
    pi2.CreateNoWindow = True
    pi2.UseShellExecute = False
```

It hides the window as supposed, but this:

```
Dim pi2 As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", String.Format("/c ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000")) With {.CreateNoWindow = True And .UseShellExecute = False}
```

Doesn't hide the window, why?

Aren't both examples the same?

Comment: Uh, aren't you missing a close double quote somewhere?  I don't see how either code sample provided would even compile correctly.

Comment: Yes i was, i just changed the full arguments to post here, sorry for that, fixed now.

Comment: Why are you using String.Format without any format specifiers?  Just pass a string.

Comment: I'm in fact Formating, i just edited the full arguments to post here as i said above, it was quite "long" and not related to my problem.
Sorry for not specifying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
With {.CreateNoWindow = True And .UseShellExecute = False}
```

is actually only setting the CreateNewWindow property and it is setting it to the inverse of the value of the UseShellExecute property.  That code is actually equivalent to this:

```
pi2.CreateNoWindow = (True And pi2.UseShellExecute = False)
```

It should have been:

```
With {.CreateNoWindow = True, .UseShellExecute = False}
```